# pandas read a file and make a list

Tags: python, import, pandas

I have to read this txt file to make an index for a table (I write only the first rows):

```
    ocmov01f
        ('TIREOO', <type 'str'>, None, 1, 1, 0, False)
        ('PROFOO', <type 'str'>, None, 10, 10, 0, False)
        ('DT01OO', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 8, 8, 0, False)
        ('DTMNOO', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 8, 8, 0, False)
        ('CDDTOO', <type 'str'>, None, 2, 2, 0, False)
        ('TDOCOO', <type 'str'>, None, 1, 1, 0, False)
        ('NROROO', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 7, 7, 0, False)
        ('NRRGOO', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 3, 3, 0, False)
        ('NSRGOO', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 3, 3, 0, False)
        ('CDAROO', <type 'str'>, None, 13, 13, 0, False)
        ('CTGMOO', <type 'str'>, None, 30, 30, 0, False)
```

The names of the columns are the strings like 'TIREOO' and then there are some infos about what type should the column content be.
I already imported successfully the table with the datas the column names refer to, but I need a fast way to import the column names (they're 132), is possible to read the file and make a list of the names? Or i have to manually make a different type of file or directly write a list of the names?

Comment: yes I already have a working DataFrame, i'll try what you suggested in a few days, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you say

> I already imported successfully the table with the datas

do you have a working `DataFrame`?

if so just use [`DataFrame.set_index()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)

the code below gets you the index you want but I've had to do some work to strip the extra `'` and `()` parts from your file.

```
import pandas as pd
from cStringIO import StringIO

data = """\
('TIREOO', <type 'str'>, None, 1, 1, 0, False)
('PROFOO', <type 'str'>, None, 10, 10, 0, False)
('DT01OO', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 8, 8, 0, False)
('DTMNOO', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 8, 8, 0, False)
('CDDTOO', <type 'str'>, None, 2, 2, 0, False)
('TDOCOO', <type 'str'>, None, 1, 1, 0, False)
('NROROO', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 7, 7, 0, False)
('NRRGOO', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 3, 3, 0, False)
('NSRGOO', <class 'decimal.Decimal'>, None, 3, 3, 0, False)
('CDAROO', <type 'str'>, None, 13, 13, 0, False)
('CTGMOO', <type 'str'>, None, 30, 30, 0, False)
"""

data = data.replace('(','')
data = data.replace(')','')

# i've named your columns so they are easier to access
# un-named, they default to integer indexing like the rows
# you probably have more meaningful names for them
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), header=None,
                 names=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])


# this is just removing the 'funny' characters from the data
df.g = [item.strip(')') for item in df.g.values]
df.a = [item.strip('(\'') for item in df.a.values]

df.set_index('a')
df
```

I should add that the I've used `from cStringIO import StringIO`,  `data = """...`, and `StringIO(data)` parts just so I could include the data directly in this answer in a runnable form.  You just need `pd.read_csv(my_data_filename, ...` in your own code

Comment: Yes I already have a working DataFrame, I need these strings to be the name of the columns.